# Interpolating between two GPS points

Tags: c#, gps, geolocation, latitude-longitude, geo

I've a huge math problem which I can't figure out. I need a function which determines a point between two locations based on a fraction between 0 and 1. The fraction represents how far between two locations a point is. So for example 0.5 is a point right in the middle between the start- and end location. So it will be something like:

```
function(coord1, coord2, 0.7){...}
```

I'm developing in c#, but if someone gives me just the math formula will be great, and also for this project I can't use external APIs which can not be downloaded locally(like Google Maps API).

Comment: To determine if spheric trigonometric formulas are required, please indicate the maximum distance between the 2 locations and the expected precision ? [spheric formulas](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm)

Comment: Well, this will be implemented in and airport, so the max length in something like 5km, but I need the maximum precision, not just the arithmetic value between this two point, because I'll receive the coordinates automatically from devices which are on track.

Comment: Look in the link mentionned in may last message : "Intermediate points on a great circle". For 5 km and a location at moretha 10° from the poles, a classical 2D computations will provide you a very good precision. I do the precision evaluation and provide it in a next comment.

Comment: For an airport located at 80°N the imprecision got by using a 2D interpolation is less than 3 meters for distances under 5 km.

Comment: Thanks man, you are really helpful, I did a rapid test implementation and it looks like it's working. One last thing, how did you calculated the imprecision?

Comment: Considering 2 points located on 80°N at a distance of 5 kilometers from each other, I used the Spheric computation to get the real intermediate point and compared it to the point located on 80°N at mid longitude. What gave a difference of latitude under 1 tenth of second, i.e. 3 meters.